# Cant find magento sales order template

Tags: magento

How can i find out this template `{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}`
which is found in `app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html`. I need change the default SKU to product code. Below are the attach images of what i am looking for.

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is located here: `app/design/frontend/SOMETHING/SOMETHING/email/order/items.phtml`
`SOMETHING/SOMETHING` depends on your project, so the only option is to test. By default it is `default/default`.

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure but i think it will be `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/Email/Items/Default.php` or `/Order/Default.php`
 good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the `sales_email_order_items` handle in your layout files, to see which template is used.

Anyway by default, it's located in `sales.xml`, and the template is `email/order/items.phtml`.